# PHP Converting Decimal Time To H:M:S

Tags: javascript, php

So I'm passing a variable from Javascript into PHP that marks the Current Time on a video being played. And I have no problem passing that decimal into mySQL, but I don't want it in decimal form. The Javascript .currentTime function seems to output a float or a double in seconds. And when I try to pass that into my VARCHAR in mySQL I get an empty spot, not null, just blank. It works if I remove this code and just switch $currentTimeRaw for $currentTime. That effectively bypasses this piece of code. So I know the problem is here but I can't figure out what I did wrong.

```
$currentTimeRAW = $_GET['currentTime'];
        $minutes = 0;
        $hours = 0;
        while($currentTimeRAW >= 3600){
            $currentTimeRAW = $currentTimeRAW - 3600;
            $hours++;
        }
        while($currentTimeRAW >= 60){
            $currentTimeRAW = $currentTimeRAW - 60;
            $minutes++;
        }
        if($hours>0){
            $currentTime = $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$currentTimeRAW;
        } else if ($hours=0){
            $currentTime = $minutes.':'.$currentTimeRAW;
        } else if ($hours=0 && $minutes=0){
            $currentTime = $currentTimeRAW;
        }
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the value PHP is receiving in `$_GET['currentTime']` - there is likely to be a  _much_ easier way in PHP to get the output you desire.

Comment: I get a float like this: 186.984748

Comment: So I figure that's pretty simple, that's a 3 minute time stamp. So just while loop it to remove minutes, and add the seconds back on at the end.

Comment: `gmdate('H:i:s', 186.984748)` will print `00:03:06`. You can use `floor()` to truncate the decimal or `round()` it.